# Can I say that Bentley's Gonna Sort You Out copy paste the first measures of Ghost Rider?

Tags: similar-artists

Can I say that [Bentley's Gonna Sort You Out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IWl77o3l50) from *Bentley Rhythym Ace*

starts with a declared copy of:

[Ghost Rider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dn7SBQ6X5HU) from *Suicide*?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't sound to be an actual sample. While it's an identical rhythm and sequence of notes, it's such a brief progression (three notes and a rest) that it's possible they came up with it independently. The original song is well-known now, but it was never a hit, so it's at least possible that Bentley Rhythm Ace was not familiar with it, or that they copied it subconsciously, rather than on purpose.

It's the looping repetition of the riff that makes it feel so identical, but that's common for electronic music. Compare the Felix Da Housecat Nina Simone remix

which is clearly a different riff, but has a similar feel because of the loop.